# regex select between {{WORD}}

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking for a regular expression which can select an string included in another one when it's between {{ and }} but not if it has escaped by "\".

And I'm going to use it in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  We will be happy to help you with your code, but we aren't keen on writing it *for* you.  Show us what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not looking for the code and I lack in RegEx. I just want the RegEx itself whcih can select string between {{ and }}. Just that.

Comment: can you share some examples?

Comment: The goal is to do like: input is "{{hello}}" which output will be "hello" but if the input is "\{{hello}}" output will be "{{hello}}".
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for it.

`([^\\]|^){{[\w\W]*?}}`

For explanation have a look [here](https://regexr.com/3m60s)

Comment: Thanks but this will also select \{{word}} which I don't want to do so.

Comment: is there any space before \{{word}}?

Comment: Thanks to you I added a bit of code like this [^\\]{{[\w\W]*?}} so it fixes my need.

Comment: For sure it doesn't work if `{{word}}` happens at very beginning of input string. @Shadow4Kill

Answer (score 0):

Regex :  `(^\{{)(?<={{)(.*)(?=}})`

Test online

https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1345